# Remove rows of dataframe contained in list (without using a loop)

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

## Problem Explanation

I have a dataframe with two columns `'A'` and `'B'`. I also have a list of tuples where the first element of the tuple is an element in the column `'A'`, and the second is in the column `'B'`. I would like to remove all rows of the dataframe coinciding with the tuples.

Of course, I could just use a loop, but I want a smarter solution that would be faster and cleaner.

## Minimal Working Example

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        'A': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'a', 'd', 'a', 'c'],
        'B': [4, 2, 2, 1, 3, 4, 3, 2],
    }
)
rows_to_remove = [('a', 4), ('c', 2), ('d', 4), ('a', 3)]
```

Answer (score 3):

I would use [*boolean indexing*](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing) with [`pandas.Series.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html) :

```
m = df.agg(tuple, axis=1).isin(rows_to_remove)

df = df.loc[~m]
```

Output :

```
print(df)

   A  B
1  b  2
3  d  1
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`merge`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with indicator:

```
out = (df.merge(pd.DataFrame(rows_to_remove, columns=['A', 'B']), indicator=True, how='left')
         .query('_merge == "left_only"')
         #.drop(columns='_merge') # commented to see the logic
       )
```

Output:

```
   A  B     _merge
1  b  2  left_only
3  d  1  left_only
```

Or, combined with [`drop`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html):

```
idx = (df.merge(pd.DataFrame(rows_to_remove, columns=['A', 'B']), how='left', indicator=True)
         .query('_merge == "both"').index
      )

out = df.drop(idx)
```

Output:

```
   A  B
1  b  2
3  d  1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you `import numpy as np` you can:

```
df[~(df.values==np.array(rows_to_remove, dtype=object)[:,None]).any(0).all(-1)]
```

It is entertaining but also useful because I tested on google-colab and the performance is `274 µs ± 11.6 µs` vs `1.44 ms ± 37.7µs` from @Timeless 's solution, that I think is the best and it's the same one that came to my mind as soon as I read the question.

It would be interesting to see the difference for bigger DataFrames.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dataframe from `rows_to_remove` then append to your original dataframe and remove duplicates:

```
>>> (pd.concat([df, pd.DataFrame(rows_to_remove, columns=['A', 'B'])])
       .drop_duplicates(['A', 'B'], keep=False))

   A  B
1  b  2
3  d  1
```

Comment: This might however delete duplicates in `df` incorrectly ;)

Comment: Yes if in the original dataframe, there are already dupes I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps. you can use 'df.drop' to drop the rows/columns by index. please have a look at the below mentioned:

DataFrame.drop(labels=None, *, axis=0, index=None, columns=None, level=None, inplace=False, errors='raise')[https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop.html]